# xsd2Code Deserialize not working

Tags: .net, xml, xsd, xsd2code

I'm using XSD2Code in order to serialize and deserialize an XML document.

For some reason I'm not getting `Deserialize` method in my intellisense. When I look at the code generated by XSD2Code, I can see these methods:

```
public static SOMEOBJect Deserialize(string xml)
{
 ..........
}
```

Could someone please tell me how to call this method?

Comment: Can you show us how are you trying to call the method.

Answer (score 2):

Since I am not sure how are you trying to call the method. As the deserialize method is a static method, you might have to call like this:

```
SOMEOBJect x = SOMEOBJect.Deserialize(xml);
```

also make sure the NameSpace selected while you generated the code is the same or either imported as using statements.